# Error While creating Sales Order from Sales Quote (CR304500)

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created a Action called "CREATE SO" in Sales Quote(CR304500) screen to create Sales Order. I have created a ComboBox udf "Sales Order Type" to select "Doc Type" of the Sales Order to be created.

1. When I am selecting DocType as "SO", its giving error "Unit
   Conversion is missing". (see pic)
2. When I am selecting any other DocType it gives an error "RevisionID
   cannot be empty".(see pic)

"SO" is the default Order Type in SO Preferences. I am unable to track the error using debugger. Please suggest. Thanks. Following is my code.

```
       #region Create Sales Order

        public PXAction<CRQuote> createSalesOrder;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create SO", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
        [PXProcessButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        public IEnumerable CreateSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            QuoteMaint graphObject = PXGraph.CreateInstance<QuoteMaint>();

            foreach (CRQuote quote in adapter.Get())
            {
                //Create resultset for Quote Details
                PXResultset<CROpportunityProducts> PXSetLine = PXSelect<CROpportunityProducts,
                Where<CROpportunityProducts.quoteID,
                Equal<Required<CROpportunityProducts.quoteID>>>>.Select(this.Base, quote.QuoteID);
                List<CROpportunityProducts> QuoteList = new List<CROpportunityProducts>();
                foreach (CROpportunityProducts line in PXSetLine)
                {
                    QuoteList.Add(line);
                }
              
                bool var_orderCreated = false;
                bool erroroccured = false;
                string ErrMsg = "";

                SOOrderEntry orderGraphObjet = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
                SOOrder orderHeaderObject = new SOOrder();
                QuoteMaint currGRPH = PXGraph.CreateInstance<QuoteMaint>();
                CRQuoteExt _quoteExt = PXCache<CRQuote>.GetExtension<CRQuoteExt>(quote); 
                var Extension = this.Base.GetExtension<QuoteMaint_Extension>();

                orderHeaderObject = orderGraphObjet.CurrentDocument.Insert(orderHeaderObject);
                BAccount customer = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<CRQuote.bAccountID>>>>.Select(this.Base, quote.BAccountID);
                if (customer.Type == "CU")
                {
                    orderHeaderObject.CustomerID = quote.BAccountID;
                    orderHeaderObject.CustomerLocationID = quote.LocationID;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new PXException("Business Account not converted to Customer yet");
                }
                if (quote.CuryProductsAmount != 0)
                {
                    orderHeaderObject.CuryOrderTotal = quote.CuryProductsAmount;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new PXException("Total cannot be 0");
                }
                orderHeaderObject.CuryOrderTotal = quote.CuryProductsAmount;
                orderHeaderObject.CuryTaxTotal = quote.CuryTaxTotal;
                orderHeaderObject.OrderDesc = quote.Subject;
                orderHeaderObject.OrderType = _quoteExt.UsrOrderNbr;

                orderGraphObjet.Document.Update(orderHeaderObject);


                orderGraphObjet.CurrentDocument.Current = orderHeaderObject;
                orderGraphObjet.Actions.PressSave();

                orderHeaderObject = orderGraphObjet.CurrentDocument.Current;

                foreach (CROpportunityProducts tran in QuoteList)
                {
                    SOLine transline = new SOLine();

                    orderGraphObjet.Transactions.Insert(transline);
                    transline.OrderNbr = orderHeaderObject.OrderNbr;
                    transline.BranchID = orderHeaderObject.BranchID;
                    transline.InventoryID = tran.InventoryID;
                    transline.TranDesc = tran.Descr;
                    transline.UOM = tran.UOM;
                    transline.OrderQty = tran.Quantity;
                    transline.SiteID = tran.SiteID;
                    transline.CuryUnitPrice = tran.CuryUnitPrice;
                    transline.CuryExtPrice = tran.CuryExtPrice;
                    transline.CuryLineAmt = tran.CuryAmount;

                    CROpportunityProductsExt xOppProductExt = PXCache<CROpportunityProducts>.GetExtension<CROpportunityProductsExt>(tran);
                    SOLineExt _soLext = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(transline); 
                    _soLext.UsrXSeqID = xOppProductExt.UsrXSequenceID;
                    _soLext.UsrXGroupID = xOppProductExt.UsrXGroupID;
                    _soLext.UsrInternalRemk = xOppProductExt.UsrInternalRemk;
                    orderGraphObjet.Transactions.Update(transline);

                }
                orderGraphObjet.Actions.PressSave(); //This is the line where both the error is showing
                    
                if (orderGraphObjet != null && orderHeaderObject != null)
                {
                    orderGraphObjet.Document.Current = orderHeaderObject;
                    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(orderGraphObjet, "Document") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
                }


                yield return quote;
            }
        }


############## DAC FIELD #####################
    [PXDBString(50)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sales Order Type")]
        [PXDefault()]
        [PXStringList(new string[] { "SO", "SP", "SS" }, new string[] { "SO - Sales Order", "SP - Sales Of Project", "SS - Sales Of Service" })]
        public virtual string UsrOrderNbr { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrOrderNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrOrderNbr> { }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that when you insert your new objects into the cache, that you insert an object with it's key elements already entered.  For instance, I would add CustomerID and CustomerLocationID to orderHeaderObject and then Insert it into the Document cache.  When you do that, the Acumatica validation will fire and all the defaults will be set in your document before you try and edit them.  Same goes for your line level object, I think that's the reason you're getting both errors.  Also, I notice you trying to set the value for a few calculated fields.  If possible I would try and leave these to calculate as designed.